# Using com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsServer - how to specify protocol?

Tags: java, ssl, https

I am trying to implement a HTTPS (SSL) server in Java, and I'd like to leverage com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsServer.

I have been able to cobble together some code from different places that kind of works, but I want to be able to specify which protocols, e.g., SSLv3, TLSv!, etc. that my HTTPS server is willing able to support, but I have not been able to figure out how to do that.

I'm posting the code I have so far, and was wondering if anyone could tell me how I can add the ability to specify the protocols?

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsServer;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsConfigurator;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsParameters;

public class Test {

    static private String PROGVERSION = "V1.00";
    static private String keystoreFile = "";
    static private int listenPort = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    System.out.println("JavaHttpsServer " + PROGVERSION);

    keystoreFile = args[0];
    listenPort = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    System.out.println("keystoreFile=[" + keystoreFile + "]");
    System.out.println("listenPort=[" + listenPort + "]");


    SSLContext ssl =  SSLContext.getInstance("SSLv3");

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()); 
    KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());


    //Load the JKS file (located, in this case, at D:\keystore.jks, with password 'test'
    //store.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Eclipse-workspaces\\Test\\keystore.jks"), "changeit".toCharArray()); 
    store.load(new FileInputStream(keystoreFile), "changeit".toCharArray()); 

    //init the key store, along with the password 'changeit'
    kmf.init(store, "changeit".toCharArray());
    KeyManager[] keyManagers = new KeyManager[1];
    keyManagers = kmf.getKeyManagers();



    // Init the trust manager factory
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

    // It will reference the same key store as the key managers
    tmf.init(store);

    TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();
    ssl.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());

    // Init a configuration with our SSL context
    HttpsConfigurator configurator = new HttpsConfigurator(ssl);
    //configurator.configure(hparams);

    // Create a new HTTPS Server instance, listening on port 8000
    HttpsServer server = HttpsServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(listenPort), 0);

    server.setHttpsConfigurator(configurator);

    server.createContext("/test", new MyHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
    server.start();
    }

    static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
            String x = t.getRemoteAddress().getHostString();
            System.out.println("In handle: Request from (getHostString) = [" + x + "]");

            x = t.getRequestURI().toASCIIString();
            System.out.println("In handle: getRequestURI = [" + x + "]");

            if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("/test?stop")) {
                System.out.println("In handle: Received request to exit, so will exit now...");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            System.out.println("In handle: About to send response...");
            String response = "This is the response";
            t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
            OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response.getBytes());
            System.out.println("In handle: Finished sending response...");
            os.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the question correctly, because your code already shows, how to set the protocol. You provide the protocol in the getInstance() method of SSLContext. In your example you initialize SSLContext with SSLv3. You can use one of the strings described here:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SSLContext

To verify, which protocol your server uses, you can use the "s_client" command of OpenSSL: `openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443`